# Idiomatic conversion of node.js APIs to ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojure, electron, clojurescript

I'm writing an Electron application, and in this application I need to interact with some of the Node.js APIs - read files, get directory entries, listen to events.

Of course, I can write ClojureScript same way I would write JavaScript, but I want to know what is ClojureScripts take on callback-style APIs, streams, EventEmitters and how do I write wrappers around node.js APIs in a way that does not to look alien in ClojureScript.

To be specific:

1. How do write an API that wraps callback-style node.js API. (say, `fs.readdir`)
2. How do I interact with EventEmitter-like APIs?
3. (Probably close to p.2) How do I work with node.js streams API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, the simplest way of handling these issues is to use [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).

**Callback Style**

For example, reading a directory:

```
(def fs (js/require "fs"))

(defn read-dir [path]
  (let [out (async/chan)]
    (.readdir fs path
      (fn [err files]
        (async/put! (if err err files))
        (async/close! out)))
    out))
```

I pass the result in to a channel, even if that result is an error. This way, the caller can handle the error by doing. E.g.:

```
(let [res (<! (read-dir "."))]
  (if (instance? js/Error res)
    (throw res)
    (do-something res))
```

In my own projects I use [cljs-asynchronize](https://github.com/gilbertw1/cljs-asynchronize), which allows you to convert NodeJS callback style functions in to core.async compatible functions. For example, this is the same as the first example:

```
(defn read-dir [path]
  (asynchronize 
    (.readdir fs path ...)))
```

Lastly, for a nicer way of handling errors through channels, I personally found ["Error Handling with Clojure Async"](https://wyegelwel.github.io/Error-Handling-with-Clojure-Async/) quite useful. So, you can write the error handling code above like:

```
(try 
  (let [res (<? (read-dir "."))]
    (do-something res))
  (catch js/Error e
    (handle-error e))
```

**Streams**

Stream API's are even simpler:

```
(defn create-read-stream [path]
   (let [out (async/chan)
         stream (.createReadStream fs path)]
     (.on stream "close" #(async/close! out))
     (.on stream "data" #(async/put! out %))
     out))
```

Comment: Does try/catch example works with first snippet as is, without changes?

Comment: Yes. Basically, the <? macro (as outlined in the article) just checks if the item on the channel is an instance of `js/Error` and if so, re-throws it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is "It depends.".

Always consider all options. Just because `core.async` makes sense in one setting does not make it the best option everywhere.

It is fine to use a normal callback if that is called once only and requires no coordination with anything else (eg. `fs.readdir`).

`core.async` is great for stream like things where you get a certain chain of events that you want to accumulate into a final result (eg. `"data","data","data","close","end"`).

Promises are another option as well.

The more coordination you need the more sense `core.async` makes. If you don't need any consider the alternatives.